# Libusb-win32,DDK,"make.cmd all" ERROR: "Invalid WinDDK Directory C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\"

Tags: wdk, libusb-win32

Thanks a lot for my question,
When i compiled libusb-win32,i built ddk envirment,i met "Invalid WinDDK Directory  C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\"
but this document existed,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcVR0.png)

Help

Comment: add: os:win10 1809

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately,i resolved my problem,
there is a  stupid problem,
in the file named "make.cfg",the path cannot contain symbol of space

wrong:
"WINDDK_DIR=!WINDDK_BASE!\7600.16385.1      " 
right:
"WINDDK_DIR=!WINDDK_BASE!\7600.16385.1"